# Break a string of characters into valid words

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, recursion, dynamic-programming

I am reading a problem on Dynamic Programming. The problem is the following:

> Break a string of characters of length n into a sequence of valid
>   words. Assume that there is a datastructure that tells you if a string
>   is a valid word in constant time.

I solved it some way of mine, but then the solution I read was the following:

> Create a table T[N] which says that T[i] is true if the substring
>   [0...i] can be broken into a sequence of valid words. T[i] is true iff
>   there exists a j, 0<=j<=k-1 where T[j] is true AND S(j,k) is a valid
>   word

This is a classic formulation for DP but isn't it wrong? Shouldn't it be:

> T[i] is true iff there exists a j, 0<=j<=k-1 where T[j] is true AND
>   S(**j+1**,k) is a valid word **OR S(0,i) is a valid word**?

Otherwise I don't see how the table could ever be constructed since for example for the string:  `itsthe` we will never have `T[2] = true` if we don't take into account that `its` is a word and the next sequence is `the` i.e. `S(2+1, N)` for j = 2.
Am I right here? But how can we then find the actual words?
Example code I made for my understanding (`s.substring(i,j)` returns the substring from `i including j-1` in java):

```
int i = 0  
for(; i < s.length(); i++){  
   for(int j = 0; j > i; j++){  
       if(T[j] && dictionary.contains(s.substring(j + 1, i)){  
             T[i] = true;
             break;  
       }  
    }  
    if(dictionary.contains(s.substring(0, i + 1)){  
         T[i] = true;  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in all your corrections.

If you want to reconstruct the actual words add one more table array that will tell you the last word length you used to set `t[i]` to `true`. Lets call this array `L[i]`

> T[i] is true iff there exists a j, 0<=j<=k-1 where T[j] is true AND
>   S(j+1,k) is a valid word OR S(0,i) is a valid word? **In the first
>   case you set `L[i] = j` in the latter - `L[i] = i`.**

Then add the end you just need to recurse back from `L[n]`, where `n` is the total length of the given string.

Comment: In `L` is that the index or the length stored?

Comment: @Cratylus index. However, as you are interested only in splitting the whole string then those two somehow coincide. You can, however, use the approach i propose even if you were interested in splitting the longest part possible.

Comment: So `L[n]` will give the index of the last word and then I go to `L[n-1]` for the previous word and then `L[n-2]` etc?

Comment: @Cratylus: no, `L[n-L[n]]` ist the next one, etc.

Comment: @WolframH:I can't follow the sequence.What comes next of that?

Comment: @Cratylus For your suggestion: Yes, `L[n] will give the index of the last word` this is exactly my idea. However, `L[n - 1]` will give you the length of the last word you used to fill in all the letters upto the second to last one. Thus, usually you will not use this value when reconstructing, lest the case the last word is single letter. Thus comes what WolframH said: the second value you consider is the one in which you have subtracted the length of the last word you have used.

Comment: @Cratylus `L[n-L[n]]` - say you have "beto" then the last word is "to" and the L[4] will be 2 (one indexed, the length of the last word). Overall in `L` you have: -1 2 3 2. After you find the last word you are interested in how you split the remainder of the string. That is "be". That is why you consider L[2].

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your notation means, specifically for choosing subsequences. You mix square and round brackets, "substring [0...i]" and "S(j+1,k)"; I suggest that we always include the left hand index and never the right hand index. This is sometimes made explicit by using a square bracket on the left hand side and a round parenthesis on the right hand side: S[0...i).

If we do that, then the original phrasing is *almost* correct; there is some confusion between i and k, which should, I think, be the same, and the case i = 0 is not handled correctly. (On a related note, I think the case n = 0 (the empty string) may also not be handled correctly by your modification.)

```
Create a table T[N] which says that T[i] is true if the substring S[0...i)
can be broken into a sequence of valid words. T[i] is true iff i = 0 OR
(there exists a j, 0<=j<i, where T[j] is true AND S[j...i) is a valid word).
```

Comment: The notation is not mine.I can only assume that `[0..i]` is meant to include `i` for the reason you point out